# Is there a tool that can let me manage MemberShip SqlProvider names/passwords in SharePoint?

Tags: forms-authentication, sql-membership-provider

Currently we have a SQL Provider setup to manage a SharePoint Site Collection via Forms Based Authentication.  However I currently have no real tools to manage the users within.  I'd like to get a SharePoint based manager to I can add users, change passwords, etc. via SharePoint.  Anyone out there ever built anything?  A quick google search didn't reveal anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although not integrated in SharePoint, the IIS7 management console allows you to maintain these users.

Just navigate to a web application that has the SQL Membership provider in the web.config and click on '.NET Users'.

Answer (score 3):

You could create an application page or web part and deploy to your SharePoint site. On that page (or web part) add a [CreateUserWizard control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.createuserwizard%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Good thought, but was hoping for something out of the box

Answer (score 1):

For SharePoint 2007 you can use the Community Kit for SharePoint:
http://cks.codeplex.com/releases/view/17901

For SharePoint 2010 you can use the SharePoint 2010 FBA Pack:
http://sharepoint2010fba.codeplex.com/